# Same test for different states of the same object without persisting changes

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, testing, django-1.8

I am trying to run the same exact test on a single `obj` which is a `models.Model` instance and has some relations with other models. I do not want to persist changes in that instance, so effectively I want the same effect of the `tearDown` method which rollbacks transactions.

To illustrate this:

```
class MyTestCase(django.test.TestCase):

    def test():
        # main test that calls the same test using all 
        # different states of `obj` that need to be tested

        # different values of data that update the state of `obj`
        # with state I simply mean the values of `obj`'s attributes and relationships
        data = [state1, state2, state3]
        for state in data:
            obj = Obj.objects.get(pk=self.pk)  # gets that SINGLE object from the test db
            # applies the state data to `obj` to change its state
            obj.update(state)
            # performs the actual test on `obj` with this particular state
            self._test_obj(obj)

    def _test_obj(self, obj):
        self.assertEqual(len(obj.vals), 10)
        self.assertLess(obj.threshold, 99)
        # more assert statements...
```

This *design* has two problems:

- The changes on `obj` persist on the test database, so on the next iteration the data would be *tainted*. I would want to rollback those changes and get a *fresh* instance of `obj` as if the `test` method was just called and we are getting the data straight from the fixtures.
- If an assert statement fails I will be able to see which one it it, but I won't be able to determine **what** case (state) failed because of the `for` loop. I can `try-except` the `_test_obj_` call in the `test` method but then I wouldn't be able to tell **what** assert failed.

Does `django.test` provide any tool to run the same test for different states of the same model? If it doesn't, how can I do what I am trying to do while solving both points mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simply rollback after you're done with the object.
2. You can use the new [subTest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest) in python 3.4+

---

Here's how your code should look:

```
class TestProductApp(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.product1 = ...

    def test_multistate(self):
        state1 = dict(name='p1')
        state2 = dict(name='p2')

        data = [state1, state2]

        for i, state in enumerate(data):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                try:
                    with transaction.atomic():
                        product = Product.objects.get(id=self.product1.id)
                        product.name = state['name']
                        product.save()
                        self.assertEqual(len(product.name), 2)
                        raise DatabaseError #forces a rollback
                except DatabaseError:
                    pass
                print(Product.objects.get(id=self.product1.id)) #prints data created in setUp/fixture
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer can be improved. Rather than forcing a rollback with an error, you can simply set a rollback for the atomic block. See [set_rollback()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.set_rollback)

```
class TestProductApp(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.product1 = ...

    def test_multistate(self):
        state1 = dict(name='p1')
        state2 = dict(name='p2')

        data = [state1, state2]

        for i, state in enumerate(data):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                with transaction.atomic():
                    product = Product.objects.get(id=self.product1.id)
                    product.name = state['name']
                    product.save()
                    self.assertEqual(len(product.name), 2)
                    transaction.set_rollback(True) # forces a rollback
                print(Product.objects.get(id=self.product1.id)) #prints data created in setUp/fixture
```